# cannot send json data from html to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I cannot send JSON Data from HTML to PHP with jquery and always show fail status at console.log. Please check my code.

```
jsonObjects.domain = client_domain;
jsonObjects.pkg = client_package;
jsonObjects.company_name = client_company;
jsonObjects.company_email = client_email;
jsonObjects.personal_name = psn_name;
jsonObjects.personal_phone = psn_phone;
jsonObjects.personal_email = psn_email;

var JsonPush = new Array();
JsonPush.push(jsonObjects);

var JsonArray = JSON.stringify(JsonPush);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'order.php',
    data: JsonArray,
    dataType: 'json',
})
.done(function (data) {
    console.log('done');
    console.log(data);
}).
fail(function (data) {
    console.log('fail');
    console.log(data);
});
```

`Order.php` file

```
<?php 

$decoded = json_decode($_POST['data']);

var_dump($decoded);
?>
```

Comment: what exactly is failing? Edit your post to include the error message

Comment: If it's failing then the problem is almost certainly in `order.php`. You will need to post that code.

Comment: <?php 

$decoded = json_decode($_POST['data']);

var_dump($decoded);
?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to stringify first, just post it in a keyed object and access via the key like this

```
 let postData = { object: jsonObjects };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'order.php',
        data: postData,
        dataType: 'json',
    })
```

Then in php:

```
$jsonObjects = $_POST['object'];
```

*note: you don't access the posted variable by the name of the object itself but rather the keys inside the posted object*

Answer (score 0):

You have no `data` parameter in your AJAX call. It should be:

```
data: { data: JsonArray },
```

But there really isn't any need to use JSON at all. You can just given an object as the `data:` option, and its properties will become `POST` parameters.

```
data: jsonObjects,
```

Then in PHP you can access `$_POST['domain']`, `$_POST['pkg']`, etc.